# start method within new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I have method `PatchUpdates` which calls `CheckConnection` method to check the connection to remote pc if true then it will get back to first method to user interface and do some other stuff

I searched and found that I need to use threading so I am creating new thread 
but my application hung and stops and nothing happen

please what I have done incorrect ?

thanks

```
        public void PatchUpdates()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow OfficeListRow in DGV_OfficeList.Rows)
                {
                    string vIPAddress;
                    string vSoruceFilePath;
                    int RowNum;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow FileListRow in DGV_FileList.Rows)
                    {

                        Thread thrd = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(PatchUpdates));
                        thrd.Start();

                        vIPAddress = OfficeListRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        vSoruceFilePath = FileListRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                        RowNum = OfficeListRow.Index;
                        ///Check the connection to pc
                        if (CheckConnection(vIPAddress) == true)
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show(vIPAddress + " Pingable ");
                            DGV_OfficeList[2, RowNum].Value = "Online";
                            OfficeListRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show(vIPAddress + " Not Pingable ");
                            DGV_OfficeList[2, RowNum].Value = "Offline";
                            OfficeListRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }



    public static bool CheckConnection(string IPAddress)
    {
        bool vPingable = false;

        try
        {
            Ping png = new Ping();
            PingReply PngReply = png.Send(IPAddress);
            vPingable = PngReply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
        return vPingable;
    }
```

Comment: Use Async Ping so you can do multiple pings at the same sime.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `thrd.Start();` Run the code. How many times do you hit the breakpoint? Why do you think that is?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `PatchUpdates` to the ThreadStart delegate from within the `PatchUpdates()` method.

```
Thread thrd = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(PatchUpdates));
thrd.Start();
```

This means that `PatchUpdates()` method starts itself over again on a new second thread, where it will start itself over again on a new third thread, where it will start itself over again on a new fourth thread, an so on...

Basically you are starting infinite new threads (as long as there are items in `DGV_FileList.Rows`), which will consume all your resources eventually.